# How to get a file size on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

As the title said, if I don't want to open the specified file, how can I get its file size from the file attribute on windows phone? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot do this without opening the file. You will have to open stream and check its Length. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefilestream%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
**EDIT** - sample code added
You probably know how to do this, in case not - here is the sample code:

```
    private long fileLength(string path)
    {
        long fileLength = -1;
        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = ISF.OpenFile(path, FileMode.Open))
                fileLength = file.Length;
        }
        catch { }

        return fileLength;
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

The easiest is to use the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class.

Here's how to do it:

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(filePath);
Debug.WriteLine("File size=" + info.Length);
```

Comment: I see that my answer is deprecated - thank you for the info. The OP should now change the acceptance.